# Does Azure monitor all instances of an app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I have a .net app in azure and it is scaled out to 10 instances.
Now i want to run an api call to see if the app returns a valid status of 200. But there could be 1 instance that is unhealthy  whereas the api call ran on a healthy instance.

How can i run the api call on all the different instances to see if i get back a valid code and the one that doesnt i will remove it ?

I have the following script

```
 $instances = az webapp list-instances --name $webAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup
foreach ($instance in $instances) {
    $instanceIpAddress = $instance.IpAddress
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "http://$instanceIpAddress" -Headers 
$Headers
}
```

The problem is that the ipAddress is not returned in the az webapp list-instances ?
also if it is the outboundip address there could be more than 1 address so how do i know what address that instance is running on ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want  is already available by using the already present [Health Check feaure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet):

> - When given a path on your app, Health check pings this path on **all instances** of your App Service app at 1-minute intervals.
> - If an instance doesn't respond with a status code between 200-299 (inclusive) after 10 requests, App Service determines it's unhealthy and removes it from the load balancer for this Web App. The required number of failed requests for an instance to be deemed unhealthy is configurable to a minimum of two requests.
> - After removal, Health check continues to ping the unhealthy instance. If the instance begins to respond with a healthy status code (200-299), then the instance is returned to the load balancer.
>   -If an instance remains unhealthy for one hour, it's replaced with a new instance.
> - When scaling out, App Service pings the Health check path to ensure new instances are ready.

You can set up azure monitor alerts to perform your own logic when an unhealthy instance is detected.